# Retorno errado ao agrupar linhas de um data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

Estou trabalhando com um dataframe e tenho o objetivo de agrupar as linhas que possuem o mesmo conteúdo na primeira coluna (Curso, que são fatores).
Ultilizo portanto os seguintes comandos:

```
library(dplyr)

data.test2 %>%
  group_by(Curso) %>%
  summarise(Total_Vagas1 = sum(data.test2$`Vaga 1 Sem`))
```

Com isso, meu data frame que era mais ou menos assim:

```
1 ADMINISTRAÇÃO                12  
2 ADMINISTRAÇÃO                45
3 ADMINISTRAÇÃO                86
4 ARTE E MÍDIA                 35
5 ARTE E MÍDIA                 24
6 CIÊNCIAS ECONÔMICAS          55
7 CIÊNCIAS ECONÔMICAS           5
8 CIÊNCIAS ECONÔMICAS         255
```

Retorna assim:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Curso               Total_Vagas1
  <fct>                      <int>
1 ADMINISTRAÇÃO                517
2 ARTE E MÍDIA                 517
3 CIÊNCIAS ECONÔMICAS          517
```

Reparem que o R somou o valor de todas as linhas da coluna `"Vagas 1 Sem"` e adicionou esse valor a cada uma das linhas. O que eu quero, na verdade, é o valor de vagas de administração, agronomia etc em sua respectiva linha.

**Dados em formato `dput`**

```
data.test2 <-
structure(list(Curso = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("ADMINISTRAÇÃO", 
"ARTE E MÍDIA", "CIÊNCIAS ECONÔMICAS"), class = "factor"), 
`Vaga 1 Sem` = c(12L, 45L, 86L, 35L, 24L, 55L, 5L, 255L)), 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Olá yoyo. Veja neste tópico como produzir um exemplo mínimo reproduzível em R: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta Não quer votar para reabrir? A pergunta agora está reprodutível.

Comment: Não tenho esse privilégio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remova o `data.test2$` de *sum(...*, ou o dplyr irá entender que é para usar a soma total em cada grupo.

```
library(dplyr)

# Dados de exemplo
set.seed(876)
dados <- tibble(Curso = as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 3)),
                Vagas = sample(20:100, 12))
names(dados)[2] <- "Vaga 1 Sem"

> sum(dados$`Vaga 1 Sem`)
[1] 720

> dados %>% group_by(Curso) %>% summarise(Total_Vagas1 = sum(dados$`Vaga 1 Sem`))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Curso Total_Vagas1
  <fct>        <int>
1 A              720
2 B              720
3 C              720
4 D              720

> dados %>% group_by(Curso) %>% summarise(Total_Vagas1 = sum(`Vaga 1 Sem`))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Curso Total_Vagas1
  <fct>        <int>
1 A              201
2 B              140
3 C              202
4 D              177
```